# Passing data into foundation modals using angularjs repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm making a "members" page for a website, which has 3 columns of pictures and names for each member.  I want to be able to click on the picture to get more information about that member (via Foundation's modal).  I'm using a repeater to display the pictures, but I'm stuck on how to pass member data into the modal so that when I click on person A, the modal will have person A's data.

Here is what I have so far:

I store the members as a json list in `members.json`:

```js
{
    "current" :  [
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "pic": "http://www.placehold.it/300x300",
        "id": "blah",
        "position": "position 1",
        "bio": "Hi I am Bob"
    },

    {
        "name": "Bobby",
        "pic": "http://www.placehold.it/300x300",
        "id": "blah",
        "position": "position 2",
        "bio": "Hi I am Bobby"
    }
    ]
}
```

And here is my controller, uses the json file:

```js
var app = angular.module('app').controller('memberCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    'use strict';

    $http.get('/data/members.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.members = data;
        $scope.numColumns = 3;
        $scope.current_rows = [];
        $scope.current_rows.length = Math.ceil($scope.members.current.length / $scope.numColumns);
        $scope.current_cols = [];
        $scope.current_cols.length = $scope.numColumns;      
    });
}]);
```

And here is my html:

```html
<!-- My attempt at the modal -->
<div ng-controller="memberCtrl" id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <center>
    <!-- The following remains blank -->
    <h2>{{members.current[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index].name}}</h2>
      </center>
      <p class="lead">Bio.</p>
      <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>


<!-- This creates a 3 column array of member profiles (it works) -->
<div ng-controller="memberCtrl">
  <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="row in current_rows">
    <div class="large-4 columns" data-ng-repeat="col in current_cols">
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal"><img ng-src="{{members.current[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index].pic}}"></a>      
      <center>
    <small><h3>{{members.current[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index].name}}</h3></small>
    <small><h4>{{members.current[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index].position}}</h4></small>
      </center>          
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ng-click attr in the img:

```
<img ng-src="{{members.current[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index].pic}}" 
     ng-click="loadMember(members.current[$parent.$index * numColumns + $index]);"/>
```

And add the function in the controller:

```
$scope.loadMember = function (member) {
    //you should be able to access the current member
    console.log(member);
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VmkB/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Cool!  So in controller function, I did `$scope.memberData = member;`  In my modal, I tried to access the value with `<p>{{memberData.bio}}</p>`.  However, I get `<p class="ng-binding"></p>`

Comment: Whoops!  Turns out that `<div ng-controller="memberCtrl" id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">` was causing the problem.  I moved the `ng-controller` to a separate div, and it worked!  Thanks!